# How to make a cell conditionally negative? (Excel)

Tags: excel

I am dealing with monthly accruals in an Excel worksheet.  I want to write a function or macro that makes it so when the month changes the values become negative. 
What I have is a column (K) where it has the month, and another cell (M18) that has the month, And I want the values in the Amount (N) column to become negative if K=M18. But 
=if($K21=$M$18,N=N*-1,"") doesn't work. I can write another column off to the side, say Q, where I can write `=if($K21=$M$18, N*-1, "")`, but I really need for the value in the N column itself to be negative.  Is there a way to write a macro or nested functions to replace the value of N with a negative version of itself conditionally? If I have to make the value of negative N calculate in Q, can I then make a second function that goes back and makes N=Q?

K_**__***L***__*M*__*_*___***N*

____*Input previous month*

____*February*

__*_***Venue_**Vendor**_Amount**
February    ***_*__*_*___***1,666

February*    __*_*__*_**3,240

February*    __*_*__*_*_718

Comment: You can't do `=if($K21=$M$18,N=N*-1,"")`, because `N` is not a valid cell address. Something like `=if($K21=$M$18,N1=N1*-1,"")` will certainly work.  It would be fairly easy to do a macro to check for this and update column N, if you don't want to add additional columns to perform this computation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro to do the trick:

```
Sub AccrualsMacro()

Dim rngN As Range
Dim clVal As Double
Dim cl As Range
Dim makeNegative As Boolean

makeNegative = [K21] = [M18]

If makeNegative Then
    Set rngN = Range("N1", Range("N1").End(xlDown))
    For Each cl In rngN
        With cl
            clVal = .Value
            If Not clVal < 0 Then 'only apply this rule if the value is still positive
               .Value = -1 * clVal
            End If
        End With
    Next
End If

End Sub
```